# Python: An elegant way to delete empty lists from Python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary as:

```
default = {'a': ['alpha'], 'b': ['beta','gamma'], 'g': []}
```

I wish to eliminate the empty values as:

```
default = {'a': ['alpha'], 'b': ['beta','gamma']}
```

I wrote a function (following an example found on the web)

```
def remove_empty_keys(d):
    for k in d.keys():
        try:
            if len(d[k]) < 1:
                del[k]
        except:
            pass
        return(d)
```

I have the following questions:

1- I didn't find the mistake why it always returns following -

```
remove_empty_keys(default)
 {'a': ['alpha'], 'b': ['beta'], 'g': []}
```

2- Is there a built-in function to eliminate/delete Null/None/empty values from Python dictionary without creating a copy of the original dictionary?

Comment: Your question seems to mix the idea of `None` with empty lists. It makes it harder to understand.

Comment: Perhaps a better way to say it would be "Is there a function to eliminate falsy values from a dictionary"

Comment: Your `try...except` clause seems to serve no purpose except to hide your own errors from yourself.  If you really want to use try/except, then you should always specify the exception(s) that you expect (in this case KeyError).  That way, they won't unintentionally hide unrelated bugs.  But in this case, unless there's code in a parallel thread that's modifying `d`, you won't ever get a key error because `k` *must* be in `d` since it was returned by `d.keys()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To fix your function, change `del[k]` to `del d[k]`. There is no function to delete values in place from a dictionary.

What you are doing is deleting the variable `k`, not changing the dictionary at all. This is why the original dictionary is always returned.

Rewritten, your function might look like:

```
def remove_empty_keys(d):
    for k in d.keys():
        if not d[k]:
            del d[k]
```

This assumes you want to eliminate both empty list and `None` values, and actually removes any item with a "false" value.

Comment: In Python 2, iterating over `d.keys()` (which was a list) made it possible to delete the values in the loop. In Python 3, `d.keys()` is [lazier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views). Iterate over `list(d)` instead, or construct a new dictionary as in [@mgilson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14813423/1307866)

Answer (score 14):

There's no builtin for this (AFAIK), but you can do it easily with a dict comprehension:

```
new_dict = {k:v for k,v in original_dict.items() if v}
```

If you're stuck with an older version of python (pre 2.7 without dict comprehensions), you can use the dict constructor:

```
new_dict = dict((k,v) for k,v in original_dict.items() if v)
```

Note that this doesn't operate in place (as per your second question).  And dictionaries don't support slice assignment like lists do, so the best* you can really do to get this all done in place is:

```
new_dict = {k:v for k,v in original_dict.items() if v}
original_dict.clear()
original_dict.update(new_dict)
```

*of course the term "best" is completely subjective.

Answer (score 5):

You can use dict comprehension: -

```
>>> default = {'a': ['alpha'], 'b': ['beta','gamma'], 'g': []}

>>> {key: value for key, value in default.iteritems() if value}
{'a': ['alpha'], 'b': ['beta', 'gamma']}
```

Comment: The problem isn't modifying the dict as you're iterating over it -- I actually think that might be OK (though don't quote me on that).  It's that OP is doing `del [k]` instead of `del d[k]`.  It seems to me that the first form is creating a list and then deleting it (though I could be wrong about that since `del` is a statement ...

Comment: @mgilson. Yeah just noticed that. I'll remove that line.

Answer (score 4):

```
dict((k, v) for k, v in default.iteritems() if v)
```

This filters all items which are not empty strings, empty dict/tuple/list.

Answer (score 2):

One more option is the following (without creating a new dict):

```
for e in [k for k,v in default.iteritems() if len(v) == 0]: default.pop(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14813529/284795) is correct.

Stepping back, you might be able to avoid creating those empty lists at all, by use of [`collections.defaultdict(list)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {})
>>> d["hobbits"].append("Frodo")
>>> d["hobbits"].append("Sam")
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'hobbits': ['Frodo', 'Sam']})
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values are all lists, so you can use their truth's, you could use [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
from itertools import compress
d = {'a': ['alpha'], 'b': ['beta','gamma'], 'g': []}
new_d = dict(compress(d.items(), d.values()))
print(new_d)  # {'a': ['alpha'], 'b': ['beta', 'gamma']}
```